# what is the meaning for this (->)symbol what it realty do?

Tags: php

am newer to  php i find lot's of code given symbol like (->)

for ex:

```
 $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM jqm_categories");
```

here getting some values from table jqm_categories and   `global $db;` it was database  config file  given below

```
/*
    This file creates a new MySQL connection using the PDO class.
    The login details are taken from includes/config.php.
*/

try {
    $db = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=UTF-8",
        $db_user,
        $db_pass
    );

    $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    die("A database error was encountered");
}
```

Here why they used "->" symbol

Answer (score 1):

the official name for this sign is **object operator**. this sign accesses a member of an object. So `$wp_query->no_of_pages` is accessing the field `no_of_pages` in the object `$wp_query`. It can be used to access either a method or a field belonging to an object.
in **C++** or **Java**, it's equivalent to `myObject.myField`

for more understanding, you can refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to access to a property from a object.

> Within class methods non-static properties may be accessed by using ->
>   (Object Operator): $this->property (where property is the name of the
>   property). Static properties are accessed by using the :: (Double
>   Colon): self::$property. See Static Keyword for more information on
>   the difference between static and non-static properties.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP is an object-oriented language, which means that variables can be declared as a particular "type", and can be thought of as "objects". This is an extreme simplification, but that `->` arrow operator is a way for an object to access the data that belongs to it.

So if you had a class called `Person`:

```
class Person
{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
}
```

and you created a new `Person` object and called it `$someone`, then you'd be able to get that `Person`'s last name by calling `$someone->lastName`;

There a lot more to it so I suggest reading up on it in the PHP documentation:

Comment: thanks and one more question in mvc based web development view folder consist _home.php like the using _before file name what that ?

Answer (score 0):

`"->"` is called as object operator or arrow in normal language.
It is used to access an object..

**In short:**

It is equivalent to `.`(DOT) notation used in java. just like `.` in `System.out.println("hello");`